# Elided or "Hidden" Text in a Python Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

According to http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#more, in Tk/Tcl it is possible to embed "elided" text in a Text widget, text that is not displayed.  This sounds useful.  Is this functionality available in Python?  If so, what is the API?

Comment: it seems you have all needed information in your link - so use them.

Comment: @furas  Oops. You are right. It's as simple as the interface appears, only it's undocumented in all the Tkinter docs I've seen. But, sure enough, `Text.tag_config('hidden', elide=1)` does the trick.  I thought it might require a call directly to the Tk subsystem. But, of course, now I see plenty of other references to `elide` here on SO. Thank you, Sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Furas is quite right... The solution is as simple as the `elide=True` keyword arg passed to the `tag_config()` method.  It's strange that the `elide` keyword is not documented in any Tkinter docs I can find.  But, the simplest scenario is to create a tag config as follows:

```
textWidget.tag_config('hidden', elide=True) # or elide=1
```

This will cause the tagged text to be "invisible" or "hidden" in the text widget. You will not be able to see the text in the Text widget, but it is still there.  If you call `textWidget.get('1.0', 'end - 1c')`, you'll see the hidden characters in the text returned by the method.  You can also delete the hidden characters from textWidget without needing to see them.  As you're deleting the elided characters, you won't see the INSERT cursor move.  It's a bit odd...

Note that the tagged text can span multiple lines, so all lines are collapsed in the Text widget.  The first thing I thought of while testing this was that, if I were implementing a source code editor and wanted to add the feature of "collapsing" part of the code (say, in an `if` block), elided text would be the feature I would want to be using to do that.

Thanks, Furas!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43417822/7032856) claims that `elide` will be refined in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Below example produces a `Text` widget that has elided text in it, using `tags`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.tag_config('mytag', elide=True)
text.insert('end', "This text is non-elided.")
text.tag_add('mytag', '1.13', '1.17')

def toggle_elision():
    # cget returns string "1" or "0"
    if int(text.tag_cget('mytag', 'elide')):
        text.tag_config('mytag', elide=False)

    else:
        text.tag_config('mytag', elide=True)


tk.Button(root, text="Toggle", command=toggle_elision).pack()

root.mainloop()
```