# tk.Text: Making image_create() images searchable by RegEx

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm already pretty sure this isn't possible, but maybe someone here is really clever and knows a way. When you use `create_image` in a `tk.Text`, `tkdocs` states it is treated as any other character. This is barely true, though. It moves along with it's surrounding characters and you can use `BackSpace` on it, but other than that it is not a character, at all. It has zero length and nothing that it can be identified with in a `regular expression`. That is, I believe it can't be identified in a `re`, and that is the entire point of my actual question.

Is it possible to give the results of `create_image` some kind of an identifier that can be caught in a `regular expression`? Something like `[^every legitimate possibility]` is not going to work. I say this because you can catch the image with `.`, so you probably could catch it, by it not being "everything else". Unfortunately, clunky methods like that are really not going to work for my needs.

If it helps to understand the specific problem. I have multiple faux-carets in my widget during certain behaviors. I am also using `idlelib` to do syntax-highlighting. `idlelib` does not like my faux-carets. I have semi-solved this problem without any regex. I believe I could completely solve it if I could describe the faux-caret in regex some kind of semi-sane way.

Comment: You could add a tag to your image like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070786/13629335) and have a [hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880181/13629335). I'm not comfortable enough with tkinter.Text to write an answer in a short time. Hope it works out for you, happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is possible. You have to apply the image as `fgstipple` in a tag instead of using `image_create`. Then you can apply the tag to any imaginable character that regex recognizes. Instead of inserting images, you insert the desired dummy character (presumably some never-used whitespace character (U+200A)?), and tag it.

Alternately, since you are dealing with carets, you could just tag the character before the caret, create no new characters, and skip the regex.